# selecting options for multiple input

Tags: c++, class, input, istream

this is my first time using this site so i will do  my best to ask my question appropriately.

i am working on a name class that handles both first and last names. the problem i am having is that in setting up the istream operator>>, i can't figure out how to get my program to determine if it has reached the end of input. for example if i want to only type the first name and let the constructor handle the last name. this current bit of code will read only the first name, but when i give it both the first and last it will read them both as first names.

```
istream& operator>>(istream& is, name& e){
string f;
string l;
is>>f;
if(is.eof())
    {
        e = name(f);

    }
else
    {
        e = name(f,l);
    }

return is;
};
```

thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Have you got an example of the two alternatives for the input?

Answer (score 0):

Your if condition only appears to check for eof, regardless of whether more than one name is entered.

Perhaps you could explode the input into an array and check for multiple names using sizeof?

I'm not fully familiar with how istream operates, but I hope you find this useful.

Comment: Whilst the first line of this answer is probably on the right lines, using `sizeof()` is not useful when the result is based on something computed at runtime - `sizeof()` is done at compile-time.